# Preg replace string in php

Tags: php, regex

I have a sting like this

```
    Date,Impressions,Clicks,CTR,Orders,Orders/Click,EPC,Sales,Avg. Order,Baseline Commissions,Adjusted Commissions,Actual Commissions  01/03/2013,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 01/04/2013,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 01/05/2013,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I am trying to append comma before each "DATE" in string like this   `,01/03/2013`

I am using this code please help me to add on this code to get above output

```
$pattern = '/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/';
$replacement = ',';
$contents =preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $contents);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$contents = "01/03/2013+otherthigns";
$pattern = '/([0-9]{2})\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/';
$replacement = ',$0';
$contents =preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$pattern = '/([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4})/';
$replacement = ',$1';
$contents =preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $contents);
```

This adds comma before every date.

If you want to change the whitespace to comma, then do this:

```
$pattern = '/\s([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4})/';
$replacement = ',$1';
$contents =preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $contents);
```